# ValueError: Input 0 of layer sequential is incompatible with the layer: expected ndim=4, found ndim=3. Full shape received: [32, 64, 3]

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning, tensorflow2.0

I am absolutely beginner in the deep learning, I am trying to build simple classification model by using the Tensorflow. Of course, I want to save my model after training by using this command.

```
model.save('saved_model/my_model')
```

after that, I want to use my model another place as well as on the raspberry pi. But, I got some error:

> ValueError: Input 0 of layer sequential is incompatible with the
>   layer: expected ndim=4, found ndim=3. Full shape received: [32, 64, 3]

Here is my model structure:
[image: my model]

Here is my test code:

[image]

Answer (score -1):

My fault, Perhaps I couldn't research enough. But, I have found the solution.

In the model the data is normalized by being devided by 255.

```
...
img = img / 255.0
img = cv2.resize(img, (64, 64))
...
```